# PHP search and result at the same page with prepared statements

Tags: php, forms, search, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make a simple form with two inputs /firstName and lastName/ and the result to be after the form /in the same page/. I have read a lot about that but can't figure why isn't working.

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="firstName" />
        <input type="text" name="lastName" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
        $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

        $DBH = new mysqli ($host,$user,$pass,$dbname);
        if ($DBH->connect_errno){
                print $DBH->connect_error;
                exit;
        }

        $DBG->query("SET NAMES utf8");
        $query = 'SELECT students.firstName, students.lastName, subjects.Name, evaluation.grad 
        FROM students, subjects, evaluation, proffessors
        WHERE professors.firstName = ? AND professors.lastName = ?
        AND students.FN = evaluation.FN AND evaluation.SSN = professors.SSN
        AND evaluation,subjectId = subjects.id';

        $stmt = $DBH->prepare($query)
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$firstName, $lastName)
        $stmt->execute()
        $result = $stmt->get_result()

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<br><p><b>First Name:  </b></b></b>", $row['firstName'], "</p>";
        echo "<br><p><b>Last Name:  </b></b>", $row['lastName'], "</p>";
            echo "<br><p><b>grade:  </b></b></b></b>", $row['grade'], "</p>";
            echo "<br><p><b>name:  </b></b></b></b></b>", $row['name'], "</p>";
}
        $result->free();
        $stmt->close();
        $DBH->close();
}
?>
```

I have try with _GET and _POST the result is the same the page get's refresh and there isn't any result.

Comment: Try adding var_dump($_POST); before if(isset($_POST['submit'])) and see the values.

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: I just didn't add the HTML i have it in my file. I add var_dump($_POST) and the result is the inputs: array(3) { ["firstName"]=> string(10) "Живко" ["lastName"]=> string(12) "Иванов" ["submit"]=> string(6) "Search" }

Comment: You are joining four tables and you do an exact match. Changes are that you throw away the baby with the bathwater. In other words, you might not be left with any result, ever. Try to spell correctly: `proffessors` and `professors`? use `LIKE` and use `JOIN` and think about the type of join. Best thing to start with is probably to enable error reporting.